# Http Basic Auth issue with Rarst/release-belt

Tags: php, .htaccess, cgi, basic-authentication, fastcgi

https://github.com/Rarst/release-belt

I have a fresh installation of the above git and my .htaccess in the public folder looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

CGIPassAuth On
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
#SetEnvIfNoCase Authorization "(Bearer .+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

FallbackResource /index.php
```

What is happening is if I have a set user, the page is refreshing, and throwing the error in the screenshot below. I can then still log in correctly through the web. If I try to use composer to add a package I get access unauthorized even with the auth.json having the correct details. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Answer (score 1):

I think FastCGI is generally iffy for Http Basic with PHP.

The middleware, that Belt uses to implement it, has following setup recommendation for such case:

> By default Apache does not pass credentials to FastCGI process. If you are using mod_fcgi you can configure authorization headers with:
>
> ```
> FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -host 127.0.0.1:9000 -pass-header Authorization
> ```
>
> https://github.com/tuupola/slim-basic-auth#usage-with-fastcgi